# Evento en un boton de cada Item de un Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` cargado desde datos de Firebase, necesito agregar una funcionalidad a un botón que se encuentra en cada item, el cual es para agregar un producto al carrito de compras.

El problema que tengo sucede cuando hay mas de un item en el recycler, ya que al hacer click en el botón se agrega correctamente un item, pero los demas ya no se pueden agregar.

Lo que quiero es hacer el onclik para cada item y al parecer solo me lo toma una vez.

```
@Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, final Menu model, int position) {

            final String item_id  = getRef(position).getKey();

            final String rest_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("rest_id");


            viewHolder.setName(model.getNombre());
            viewHolder.setDescrpcion(model.getDescripcion());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getThumb_image());
            viewHolder.agregaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mEstado_pedidos.equals("sin_pedidos")){

                        Map pedidoMap = new HashMap();
                        pedidoMap.put("Solicitud_Pedido/"+mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + rest_id + "/" + item_id + "/tipo_pedido", "solicitado");
                        pedidoMap.put("Solicitud_Pedido/"+rest_id + "/" + mCurrent_user.getUid() + "/" + item_id +"/tipo_pedido", "recibido");

                        mRootRef.updateChildren(pedidoMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                                if (databaseError != null){

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                                fab.setEnabled(true);
                                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                mEstado_pedidos = "con_pedido";
                                Button agregaBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);
                                agregaBtn.setText("Eliminar del carrito");

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            });

            final String list_user_id  = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });


        }
```

esta es mi clase `ViewHolder`:

```
public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;Button agregaBtn;


    public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        agregaBtn = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);


    }


    public void setName(String nombre){

        TextView mName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_item);
        mName.setText(nombre);
    }

    public void setDescrpcion(String descrpcion){

        TextView mDescripcion = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_item);
        mDescripcion.setText(descrpcion);
    }

    public void setImage(final Context context, String thumb_image){

        ImageView mImagen = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_item);
        Picasso.with(context).load(thumb_image).into(mImagen);

    }

}
```

Comment: podrias agregar una captura del error? no se entiende cual es el problema.

Comment: En el momento no cuento con las images, pero te explico. Al hacer clic en el btn "Add to cart" en cualquiera de los items del recycler se agrega pero solo el primero  ya sea que de clic en el segundo o tercer item. Tambien  tengo programado para que cambie el txt del btn a "eliminar", una vez se ha agregado un item, pero este tambien cambia solo en el primer item de la lista no se como hacer para que cada item haga el escucha y no se agregue solo uno sino los que yo quiera. ya que ese es mi problema que solo se agrega el primer item de la lista y no funciona mas el btn en ninguno de los demas.